# How to change columns set of kendo grid with JQuery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to change the columns Kendo grid like below but it didn't work

```
$("#AddGrid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: AddGriddataSource,
  selectable: "row",
  scrollable: false,
  columns: AddGridCells,
  change: numberInput,
    pageable: {
      buttonCount: 3,
      messages: GridPageMsg
    },
  height: '100%',
  editable: true
}).data("kendoGrid");

var AddGriddataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [],
  schema: {
    model: {
      fields: {
        No: { editable: false, nullable: false },
        Num: { editable: true, nullable: false }
      }
    }
  }, 
});

var AddGridCells = [
  { field: "No", title: "No", width: "20px" },
  { field: "Num", title: "Num", width: "40px", template: '<input  id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value= #=Num# style="margin: 4px" />
];
```

and new Cell and Source below

```
var newGridCells = [
  { field: "No", title: "No", width: "20px" },
  { field: "Num", title: "Num", width: "40px", template: '<input  id="Txt_test" class="k-state-disabled" type="textbox" value= #=Num# style="margin: 4px" />'
];

var newGriddataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [],
  schema: {
    model: {
      fields: {
        No: { editable: false, nullable: false },
        Num: { editable: false, nullable: false }
      }
    }
  }, 
});
```

**JQuery below  but it only change DataSource, the newGridCells can't work**

```
var grid = $("#AddGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.setDataSource(newGriddataSource );
grid.setOptions(newGridCells);
```

**does any idea to change the columns ? like below**

```
if(status == 1){
  **use initial value**
} else{
  **use newGriddataSource and newGridCells** 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `columns` inside grid options, not options itself.

Something like this:

```
var grid = $("#AddGrid").data("kendoGrid");

var newGridCells = [
  { field: "No", title: "No", width: "20px" },
  { field: "Num", title: "Num", width: "40px", template: ''}
];

var gridOptions = grid.getOptions();

gridOptions.columns = newGridCells;

grid.setOptions(gridOptions);
```

Working example: [set cells](https://dojo.telerik.com/abIxuZid)